# Ember.js Undefined links in the Url

Tags: ember.js

since a few days im working with ember.
After watching some of the guides, i tried to make an ember-application similiar to the getting-started example.

But i have problem and i dont find the solution.
I build a "Posts" template which shows a list of all Posts with a view params like author etc.
Then i wrote a Post template in which you can see more details of this Post.
If you click in the posts-List on one post, then it should link to a new Site with the post. The Post-Id should be in the url for the routing but that doesent work .. the link (or the id) is always 'undefined'.

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                {{#each}}
                <div class="postcontainer">
                    <div class = "voteSection">
                        <div class="pointAndVotingUp">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="points">
                            {{votesUp}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="pointAndVotingDown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "postSection">
                        <div class="post">
                            {{#link-to 'post' this }}
                            {{title}}
                            {{/link-to}}
                            {{format-markdown content}}
                            <small class="muted">asked {{format-date time}} by {{author}}</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class= "tagSection">
                            <div class= "tag">
                                {{tag1}}
                            </div>
                            <div class= "tag">
                                {{tag2}}
                            </div>
                            <div class= "tag">
                                {{tag3}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class= "answerSection">
                                3 people already answered. 
                                {{#link-to 'post' this }}
                                    Submit your own answer...
                                {{/link-to}}
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
            <!--
            <div class="span9">
                {{outlet}}
            </div>
            -->
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <hr>
    <!--
    <div class='intro'>
      {{format-markdown excerpt}}
    </div>
    -->

    <div class='below-the-fold'>
      {{format-markdown content}}
    </div>

    <h2>by {{author}} <small class='muted'>({{format-date date}})</small></h2>

    {{#if isEditing}}
    {{partial 'post/edit'}}
    <button class="btn btn-default" {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Done</button>
    {{else}}
    <button class="btn btn-default" {{action 'edit'}}>Edit</button>
    {{/if}}
  </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post/_edit">
    <p>{{input type="text" value=title}}</p>
    <p>{{input type="text" value=excerpt}}</p>
    <p>{{textarea value=body}}</p>
</script>
```

EmberApp:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('posts');
    this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id'});
});
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {   

          return jQuery.getJSON("/posts/" + params.post_id);
    }
});
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
       return posts.findBy('id', params.post_id);     
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
    // this will make the URL `/posts/12`
    return { post_id: model.id };
  }
});

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,

    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        doneEditing: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        }
    }

});
```

At the moment the posts are hardcoded like this:

```
var posts = [{
    _id: '1',
    points: 10,
    title: "foo title",
    author: { name: "Hans" },
    date: new Date(2013, 11, 12), 
    excerpt: "foo text foo"
}, ...
```

pls can someone tell me where is the mistake?

```
Settings:
DEBUG: ----ember-1.2.0.js:3386
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.2.0 ember-1.2.0.js:3386
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 ember-1.2.0.js:3386
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2 ember-1.2.0.js:3386
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Comment: will you modify this jsbin with all of your code, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ECaDOSIH/1/edit .

Comment: Give these a try, when you define the model in posts route, just do return this.get('store').find("post"), similarly in post route define the model as this.get('store').find('post',params.post_id). Which version of ember data are you using? if you are using the latest one, give this a read https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: created a jsbin with the code posted by the OP http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EFowejU/1#/posts and it seems to work ok if the components `format-markdown`, `format-date` are excluded from the templates

Comment: sry, but i did a mistake, with id it works, but the post_id from the server comes not as 'id' but as '_id' and that is the problem .. with id it works but not with _id. But i just can  get it as _id :-(